# Intermittent connection failures to postgresql instance in kubernetes pod

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes

I am using the postgres container found here: https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

I am using the `POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust` feature

I was able to get the container running and psql is running

```
2022-03-29 15:39:19.974 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2022-03-29 15:39:19.974 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2022-03-29 15:39:19.976 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2022-03-29 15:39:19.990 UTC [88] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-03-29 15:39:19 UTC
2022-03-29 15:39:19.994 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

I am able to connect to it within this pod, but when I try to make connections from another pod, I intermittently receive one of the two following errors:

`$ psql -h postgres_container -U postgress psql: error: connection to server at "postgres_container" (172.20.207.197), port 5432 failed: received invalid response to SSL negotiation: 2`

or

`psql: error: connection to server at "172.20.127.235", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist`

If I retry my attempts, eventually I will make a successful connection and will be able to run queries on that database.

Any ideas what the issue could be?

Comment: Please provide more details about your environment: what kind of cluster is used? (Managed like GCP EKS or on-premise using `kubeadm`). Also how exactly did you try to connect to postgresql db from another pod: using IP or DNS name? I can think of some DNS issue in the cluster, but not enough details.

Comment: This is a managed EKS cluster. I've tried both dns and IP both with the same results. I've also enabled the `log_connections` config, and it seems that the failed connections are not making an entry in the postgresql logs, but the successful ones are.

Comment: It's looking more and more like this is a DNS issue

Comment: You can try to `kubectl rollout restart` CoreDns deployment, sometimes it can be started not correctly. And another option is to spin up another cluster. If it's production, then again, first is to restart coredns. If it's not helpful, there's an [article how to troubleshoot DNS in k8s](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/)

Comment: Did you resolve this?